# Cannot install jspdf 1.5.3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, jspdf, html2canvas

I need to convert html to pdf and I am using jspdf 1.5.2.
It shows the error Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined (using with html2canvas).

When I try to install jspdf 1.5.3 I get this:

```
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I have read the other threads and none of them are helpful.

Comment: 'npm is not able to find a file' it says. pls check other lines printed to see if the file is mentioned

Comment: This is the complete error. jspdf versions 1.5 and below work fine for this.

Anyway I worked around it by calling the window.print() method.

Comment: Still finding workaround as ssh/git cannot be connected

Answer (score 7):

With Version 1.5.3 of jsPDF they use a dependency directly from GitHUB. I'm assuming you're running the build in a CI? Either you install git + ssh or at that point return to version 1.5.2 of jsPDF. There's a bunch of issues in their bug tracker. This seems to be the relevant issue https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2208. It's marked fixed, but so far no new version 1.5.4.

Answer (score 5):

Try installing jspdf in ***git bash*** (GIT command line) using

> npm i jspdf

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.
I solved installing git.

Answer (score 4):

For any passerby here because of html2pdf.js failing on CI, we're in the same boat.

It requires ^1.4.1, and resolves to 1.5.3 as of now, so either:

- publish your own release on NPM rolling out the dependency fix,
- install git on your Alpine image (docker: RUN apk add --no-cache git) and pray it'll pass through your enterprise firewall (it did not for me),
- force 1.4.1 by requiring jsPDF in your package.json, and commit with the package-lock.json (worked for me).

Comment: Yeah downgrading to 1.4.1 worked for me (I'm using Bitbucket CI/Pipelines). Downgrading to 1.5.2 was causing a breaking issue with autotable so that was not an option.

Comment: Also using Bitbucket pipelines, downgrading jspdf to 1.4.1 worked for me. Apparently, pdf generating packages are dependent on the child packages of their peers, because uninstalling jspdf since I wasn't using it did nothing to help my case.

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this:

1. Install [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads).
2. Open a new cmd window.
3. Execute `npm i jspdf`.